# Regex - How to match only the lines that have <111>a followed by any number of characters but should not have context_reg="gamma"

Tags: java, regex

I tried the below regex expression

```
(<111>a)(^(?!.*context_reg="gamma".*))
(<111>a)(.*)^((?!context_reg="gamma").)*
```

to match lines

```
<111>a 2020-01-01T09:36:06.593-00:00 This is for testing context_user="rob", context_env="mac",context_reg="alpha"
```

but not match

```
<111>a 2020-01-01T09:36:06.593-00:00 This is for testing context_user="rob", context_env="mac",context_reg="gamma".
```

But the above doesn't work. Any suggestion on how to modify the regex.
I took the references from other stack overflow.

This is for java regex matcher.

Comment: Something like `(^<111>a)(?!.*context_reg="gamma".*).*$` might work.

Comment: the `^` caracter assert the first position of the string. You are checking for `<111>a` **THEN** the first caracter of the string. it does not make sense. Try removing the `^`

Comment: I would simply use *two* regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks. This is working I removed both ^ and $